# cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android

Hello How can I resolve this error
When I tried in my localhost it works fine but now I got this error

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  ..... of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

code

```
private void getdetails(String json){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
            String mdp = c.getString("Password");
            String login = c.getString("Login");
            String type = c.getString("Type");
            String d = mdp;
            String d3 = type;
            if(d.equalsIgnoreCase(et_password.getText().toString())&& d3.equals("Delegue"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailsAccount.class);
                intent.putExtra("login", et_login.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Merci de vérifier votre email et mot de passe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the response string?

Comment: No I mean the Json encoded string that you receive from the server or the file.

Comment: If the JSon encoded string starts with `[` symbol you dont need the first line of the function.

Comment: did uou mean this string org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Adresse":"aaa","Login":"rrrr","Nom":"kkkk","Email":"mmmm","NCIN":"dddd","Type":"ggg","Password":"1234","Prenom":"zzzz","longitude":"","latitude":"","Tel":"11111"}]

Comment: I had this error cannot resolve symbol jsonObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function

```
private void getdetails(String json){
    try {

        JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);
        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
        String mdp = c.getString("Password");
        String login = c.getString("Login");
        String type = c.getString("Type");
        String d = mdp;
        String d3 = type;
        if(d.equalsIgnoreCase(et_password.getText().toString())&& d3.equals("Delegue"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailsAccount.class);
            intent.putExtra("login", et_login.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Merci de vérifier votre email et mot de passe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If your JSON string is just an array you cannot convert it to an object.You would just construct a JSON array from the string itself.

Comment: On which line of the function?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can show me the string json

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Adresse":"aaa","Login":"rrrr","Nom":"kkkk","Email":"mmmm","NCIN":"dddd","Type‌​":"ggg","Password":"1234","Prenom":"zzzz","longitude":"","latitude":"","Tel":"111‌​11"}]

Comment: the erro is in this line JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(json);